# ASP.NET C# Continue row count in Gridview in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, repeater

I have a column with a Label control that is keeping the Count in a Gridview that is nested in a Repeater.  If there are 3 Gridviews displayed with 5 rows each, how do I continue the numbering in the Gridview's RowDataBound event?  Currently the Gridview's start over again at one when I use

```
(e.Row.FindControl("lblCount") as Label).Text = (e.Row.RowIndex +1).ToString();
```

Current Outcome:
Gridview1
1
2
3
4
5

Gridview2
1
2
3
4
5

Gridview3
1
2
3
4
5

Desired Outcome:
Gridview1
1
2
3
4
5

Gridview2
6
7
8
9
10

Gridview3
11
12
13
14
15

.aspx page

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptGridViews" OnItemDataBound="rptGridViews_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvProposals" OnRowDataBound="gvProposals_RowDataBound" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Count">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="lblCount" runat="server" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
         </asp:Gridview>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void gvProposals_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e){
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
  (e.Row.FindControl("lblCount") as Label).Text = (e.Row.RowIndex+1).ToString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the counter outside the event handler, a good place would before the `Page_Load` handler just after your `public partial class...`:

```
private int counter;
```

And in the `RowDataBound` event handler:

```
protected void gvProposals_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            counter++;
            (e.Row.FindControl("lblCount") as Label).Text = counter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I added my code. This is only the second question I've ever asked, so was unsure how to do it. Thanks!

Comment: How is the counter variable incremented?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Now it's there. The increment is before adding the text to the cell, because it's initially 0 and you seem to want to start row count from 1.

Comment: Glad I could help.